# When is using Angular (or a similar JS MV* framework) with Rails a good idea?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, performance, angularjs, javascript-framework

I've been developing a Rails app with a fairly straight-forward UI. When a user logs in, it lists a bunch of items created by the user. Each item has a couple actions. There is also a form to create new items.

I was originally using only the standard Rails templating system and Rails AJAX calls for actions (setting :remote => true, writing response JS, etc), but I recently decided to switch to AngularJS in order to make it easier to implement AJAX actions that directly update the DOM. On the server side, I did away with most of the Rails controllers and moved the actions into a Grape API.

The development process has gotten (slightly) easier, since there is less JavaScript to write, but the performance of the page has suffered. Now, after a page loads, an additional API call must be made in order to populate the page with data. The data is sent to the client as a fairly lengthy JSON string (even though I am gzipping it) and the client must do a lot of work to parse through it and render it all. As a result, the page takes about twice as long to load as it did before.

How can this be overcome, and in general, when does it make sense to use something like Angular in a web app that has a lot of data and is not necessarily a single-page app? It seems like the tradeoff is between having the server do more work and the performance be better in exchange for spaghetti code on the client-side, or having the client do more work and the performance drop in exchange for more beautiful, well-structured code on the client-side.

Is there some happy medium between the two? Would love to hear your thoughts....